# Displaying formants in real time

Tags: phonetics, formants

Is anybody aware of an app that will show vowel formants in real time (or more or less)? I know there are apps that will give you a spectrogram, but I can't read the output quickly or accurately enough. I've also now seen [this previous question](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/17596/where-can-i-find-a-vowel-analyzer-app-or-program) and one of the apps mentioned in the answer does do something similar (it plots vowels on a vowel quadrilateral) but the developers say that getting it to identify formants is "very much a work in progress".

Comment: Have you checked out WaveSurfer? It's not real-real time, but if you're going to be working with short clips it should get the job down.

Comment: Thanks, I had a look but I find it harder to read than Praat and it's not much closer to real time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Praat can do the exact job.

Dotted red lines represent formants, but they are not in real time.

[image: Dotted red lines represent formants, but they are not in real time]

Here is the link if you want to download it: http://www.fon.hum.uva.nl/praat/

Comment: Thanks - not real time but seems to be the best option.

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party, but I just found some tools that can do this.

- VowelWorm: https://github.com/BYU-ODH/apeworm

demo: https://byu-odh.github.io/apeworm/examples/sources.html (need an older browser to work properly)

It can display formants on a vowel chart in real time.

- InFormant: https://github.com/in-formant/in-formant

It can display spectrogram, pitch and formants in real time. Also a tons of options.

- WaveSurfer: https://sourceforge.net/projects/wavesurfer/

It can display spectrogram, pitch, formants and other stuff in real time (right click to choose). It claims to be customizable and extensible.

I'm also new to this and can't vouch for any of them, but I'm going to start with WaveSurfer, as it looks very powerful.

Comment: WRT Wavesurfer, KTH has shuffled their web pages so the only manual, which is via web page, is 404. It can eventually be made to display a passable spectrogram if you randomly click enough things, especially find the preference that allows you to pick a lower Srate mono spectrogram, then click the sheet of paper to actually display the spectrogram.

Comment: @user6726 Yes, it's a shame that the manual of WaveSurfer is 404 now. I found this (http://www.fb10.uni-bremen.de/anglistik/ling/gk-lingintro08/software/WaveSurfer%20User%20Manual.htm) which looks like an older version of the manual hosted by someone else. Better than nothing. ^^

Comment: Hi! I think this would better be served as a comment.

Comment: @MeltedStatementRecognizing Why? OP asks for tools. I give 3 tools that do what OP asks. This perfectly answers the question, actually better than the accepted answer, which gives a tool that displays formants not in real time while OP explicitly asks for one that does so in real time.